# XC32 optimizes vaiable used for register reading

Tags: pic, c, compiler, optimization, xc32

I am facing a problem with XC32 compiler's optimization. Whenever I write a function to read something from register, XC32 optimizes (read: Removes) the variable which holds the return value.

I have a wrapper function which reads a perticular pin of perticular port:

```
uint8_t u8INT_DIO_ReadRangeSelect(void)
{
    uint8_t u8pinstatus = 0;

    // Read pin assigned to Range Select input
    u8pinstatus = (uint8_t) SYS_PORTS_PinRead(PORTS_ID_0, 
            RANGE_SELECT_PORT, RANGE_SELECT_PIN);

    return u8pinstatus;
}
```

Here `SYS_PORTS_PinRead` is a harmony (PIC's code generating tool) generated code and it just reads the port pin.
Code for that is:

`return( _SFR_BIT_READ( _PORTS_READ_B_VREG(index) + ((channel-1) * 0x40), bitPos ) );`

Note that, it's an inline function.

Now, when I set Optimization level to 1, XC32 removes `u8pinstatus` variable and always returns 0.

But if I declare `u8pinstatus` as `volatile`, everything works fine (which was expected).

But then I need to declare all the variables volatile because all my wrapper functions are always returning 0. That's not a good way.

Is it that XC32 gone bonks or am I doing something wrong?

**Additional Info:**

*Assembly code with optimization*:

```
!uint8_t u8INT_DIO_ReadRangeSelect(void)
!{
0x9D00AA8C: ADDIU SP, SP, -24
0x9D00AA90: SW RA, 20(SP)
!    uint8_t u8pinstatus = 0;
!    
!    // Read pin assigned to Range Select input
!    u8pinstatus = (uint8_t) SYS_PORTS_PinRead(PORTS_ID_0, 
0x9D00AA94: ADDU A0, ZERO, ZERO
0x9D00AA98: ADDIU A1, ZERO, 3
0x9D00AA9C: JAL SYS_PORTS_PinRead
0x9D00AAA0: ADDIU A2, ZERO, 8
!            RANGE_SELECT_PORT, RANGE_SELECT_PIN);
!    return u8pinstatus;
!}
0x9D00AAA4: LW RA, 20(SP)
0x9D00AAA8: JR RA
0x9D00AAAC: ADDIU SP, SP, 24
```

*Assembly code without optimization*:

```
!uint8_t u8INT_DIO_ReadRangeSelect(void)
!{
0x9D00F998: ADDIU SP, SP, -32
0x9D00F99C: SW RA, 28(SP)
0x9D00F9A0: SW S8, 24(SP)
0x9D00F9A4: ADDU S8, SP, ZERO
!    uint8_t u8pinstatus = 0;
0x9D00F9A8: SB ZERO, 16(S8)
!    
!    // Read pin assigned to Range Select input
!    u8pinstatus = (uint8_t) SYS_PORTS_PinRead(PORTS_ID_0, 
0x9D00F9AC: ADDU A0, ZERO, ZERO
0x9D00F9B0: ADDIU A1, ZERO, 3
0x9D00F9B4: ADDIU A2, ZERO, 8
0x9D00F9B8: JAL SYS_PORTS_PinRead
0x9D00F9BC: NOP
0x9D00F9C0: SB V0, 16(S8)
!            RANGE_SELECT_PORT, RANGE_SELECT_PIN);
!    return u8pinstatus;
0x9D00F9C4: LBU V0, 16(S8)
!}
0x9D00F9C8: ADDU SP, S8, ZERO
0x9D00F9CC: LW RA, 28(SP)
0x9D00F9D0: LW S8, 24(SP)
0x9D00F9D4: ADDIU SP, SP, 32
0x9D00F9D8: JR RA
0x9D00F9DC: NOP
```

Comment: @Bence This is just an example function I am putting up... If I want to read and process some register information, That variable which holds the SFR value becomes zero and all processing goea wrong

Comment: Hmm... Then maybe you should pass a parameter to store the register value in it rather than returning a local variable.

Comment: Well, this pretty clearly sounds like a compiler bug. Make sure your dev environment is up to date. See if you can downgrade if it's that critical.. You should contact Microchip with a clear example of code that makes the error shown, with a note showing expected behavior, and showing that it behaves differently at optimization level 0. Until they respond, you may be stuck declaring all local register data holders as volatile. Another option might be the 'register' keyword for really simple stuff like this.

Comment: Is the keyword 'volatile' important here? I see it in the code used to access registers all the time.. something about preventing the compiler from optimizing out the read instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler optimizations typically assume that nothing but the program itself can alter the contents of memory. With that assumption, repeated reads from the same register on a microcontroller are often optimized out, because the compiler doesn't see anything in the code that can possibly give a different result with repeated execution. Why execute the same instructions over and over if the result will always be the same?

*Volatile* is the workaround. It tells the compiler that something else in the universe might alter that particular address in memory, and that its assumptions about future values aren't necessarily true. "Don't optimize me, bro".

In short, I think things are behaving exactly as intended.

Comment: +1 and the compiler would still be free to optimise away `u8pinstatus` as it's unused.

Comment: @David Why is the compiler allowed to optimise away u8pinstatus?

Comment: @David I am returning that variable, how it can be unused?

Comment: @Swanand @le_top because it is only used to temporarily store then return the value from an inline function. It has no other purpose and therefore can be optimised away to save local stack space (or a register allocation). A good optimising compiler would reduce that whole function call to the contents of the inline `SYS_PORTS_PinRead`.